# grails 2.4.4 issue inverting filters schema

Tags: grails, servlet-filters, grails-2.4

In a new project based on grails 2.4.4 I am using filter schema with invert option. Few controllers and some actions from another controllers are excluded in filters by inverting the rule.

Filter will not be applied to Login, ForgotPassword ans ServerError Controllers and saveUser, verifyRegistration actions from different user controller. This filter schema  doesn't work as expected.

When I am calling login api inside login controller, filter is getting executed and throws exception.

```
package com.project.filters

import grails.converters.JSON

class MyProjectAuthorizationFilters {

    def userService
    def grailsApplication

    def filters = {
        checkXAuthToken(controller:'login|forgotPassword|serverError', action:'saveUser|verifyRegistration', invert: true) {
            before = {
                try{
                    String tokenValue = request.getHeader('X-Auth-Token')
                    if(tokenValue == null && tokenValue == ""){
                        throw new MyCustomException(401, "Please provide X-Auth-Token in Header")
                    }
                    userService.getUserByAuthToken(tokenValue)
                }catch (MyCustomException error) {
                    error.stackTrace = ""
                    response.setStatus(error.status)
                    render error as JSON
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know we can also use controllerExclude, actionExclude, but did not know why this is breaking?

**EDIT**
I even tried using controllerExclude and actionExclude but it doesn't work as expected. Is this a weired behaviour or I am doing something wrong. Posting whole filter class code.

Thanks.